# File.listFiles() doesn't list files on some specific paths

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a file explorer of my own but having some problems. My code works properly, but when I try to list files on "/storage/emulated", array returns as null. I tried it on an AVD and my own phone but it's the same. Do I need some kind of privilages to access that spesific folder? I can see the contents of "/storage" and and any other path really. [a quick gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGGcv.gif)

```
package com.tetradev.projectpodcaster;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DirectoryChooser extends AppCompatActivity
{
    //Variables
    public String directory;

    //Views
    ListView fileList;
    ImageButton backFolderButton;
    TextView pathTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.directory_chooser);

        //Set the default directory.
        directory = "/storage/emulated/0";


        //Assign views by their index.
        fileList = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        backFolderButton = findViewById(R.id.backFolderButton);
        pathTitle = findViewById(R.id.pathTitle);

        //Process the default directory on start.
        setListView(getFilesFromDirectory(directory));

        //Handling the ListView click.
        fileList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                if(new File(directory + "/" + getFilesFromDirectory(directory).get(position).fileName).isDirectory())
                {
                    directory = directory + "/" + getFilesFromDirectory(directory).get(position).fileName;
                    setListView(getFilesFromDirectory(directory));
                    Toast.makeText(DirectoryChooser.this, String.valueOf(directory), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        //Handling the back folder button.
        backFolderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                //Check if there is still a parent folder left.
             if(new File(directory).getParentFile().getParentFile() != null)
             {
                 //Set path as the old ones parent.
                 directory = new File(directory).getParentFile().getPath();

                 //Reset the ListView
                 setListView(getFilesFromDirectory(directory));
             }
            }
        });
    }

    //Get all contents as a list of "FileClassess"
    public List<FileClass> getFilesFromDirectory(String path)
    {
        List<FileClass> tempFileList = new ArrayList <FileClass>();

        int fileCount = 0;

        //Check if the folder is empty.
        if(new File(path).listFiles() != null)
        {
            fileCount = new File(path).listFiles().length;

            for (File file : new File(path).listFiles())
            {
                //TEMPORARY FILE SORTER
                if(file.isDirectory())
                {
                    tempFileList.add(new FileClass(file.getName(), R.drawable.folderIcon));
                }
                else
                {
                    tempFileList.add(new FileClass(file.getName(), R.drawable.defaultFile));
                }
            }
        }

        //Set the pathTitle text.
        pathTitle.setText(path + ", " + fileCount + " files found.");

        //Return temporary list as a variable.
        return tempFileList;
    }

    //Adapt the list as a ListView.
    public void setListView(List<FileClass> filesInDirectory)
    {
        FolderChooserAdapter adapter = new FolderChooserAdapter(this, filesInDirectory);
        fileList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Do I need some kind of privilages to access that spesific folder?" -- most of the Android filesystem is inaccessible to you. You have access to a few limited locations, and that's it.

Comment: Oh, I get it! I tought that I'm doing something wrong. Thanks for the quick answer! Can you post it as an answer so I cant mark it as correct?

Comment: Try getFilesDir(), getExternalFilesDir(null) and getExternalFilesDirs(). If you add legacyExternalStorage true to manifest file you can also use getExternalStorageDirectory().

Comment: AFAIR apps don't have the permission to list files in  `/storage/emulated`. Hence no matter what you do you won't get a file listing for this directory. Additionally I am sorry but what you do is a wast of time because with [Android Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage) you can no longer access `/storage/emulated` directly. Therefore your code will only work on older devices.